# How can I stop browsers from caching my website? (if the cache really is the issue)

Tags: php, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I deactivate caching in browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6017231/how-do-i-deactivate-caching-in-browsers)

I've recently implemented a crude and hasty restrictions and blocking system for my website (i.e. clients can choose which of their users can add/delete/edit stuff or which section they are allowed to visit) and I've done it by simply removing the click events from said buttons or changing them to a 'can't do that' prompt. The problem is that the changes will only take effect after users delete their cache, which led me to believe that the browser fed them the non-restricted cache instead of the new one with the restrictions applied. Is there any way to make sure the browser doesn't cache my pages and that users always get a "fresh" version of the page?